# regular expression for six digit numbers prefixed with 3 letters

Tags: javascript, regex

Is this the correct regular?

```
^[ASB]{3}[0-9]{6,}$
```

I want to validate the number (using JavaScript) which should have three prefixed letters ASB followed by 6 digits e.g. ASB673567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the first character class,. `[ASB]` matches any one of the character from the given list, that is here it may match `A` or `S` or `B`. So by repeating the character class exactly three times, `[ASB]{3}` not only matches `ASB` but also `AAA` or `AAB` or .......

```
^ASB[0-9]{6,}$
```

This would match 6 or more digits prefixed with `ASB`

For exactly 6 digits.

```
^ASB[0-9]{6}$
```